# How to detect macOS Shortcuts cancellation in an AppIntent perform()?

Tags: macos, sirishortcuts, swift-concurrency

I'm testing with this simple AppIntent that only counts from 1 to 10 each second.

```swift
import AppIntents

struct Loop10SecCount: AppIntent {

  static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Loop 10 second count"

  static var description = IntentDescription("For debugging", categoryName: "Debug")

  func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
    for i in 1...10 {
      print("loop \(i)")

      try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))

      if Task.isCancelled {
        return .result()
      }
    }

    print("Done")
    return .result()
  }

}
```

My dev setup is I run the app in Xcode. Then open mac Shortcuts app separately, use the AppIntent that my running app provides, then watch progress in both Shortcuts app and Xcode console (I put some print statements in my app intent perform() ). I when I stop this action midway in Shortcuts, the progress in Shortcuts app stops, but in Xcode it still prints up to 10.

In Shortcuts app, it look like this when running.

[image]

When I press stop button mid way at 5 sec, I'm expecting `Task.isCancelled` to be `true` and the shortcut should stop after printing `loop 5`. In Shortcuts app it stops as expected (stop button turns to play button), but on my Xcode console it still keeps counting up to 10. So I think this is a wrong way. My `perform()` still continues.

```
loop 1
loop 2
loop 3
loop 4
loop 5
loop 6
loop 7
loop 8
loop 9
loop 10
Done
```

I tried to find other things related to cancellation, stopping, or some other info in AppIntent protocol. No clue so far.

Does anyone know how to detect shortcut cancellation?

Comment: FWIW, the `if Task.isCancelled` is redundant and it will almost never detect the cancelation because if this `async` function is canceled during the `try await Task.sleep`, it will immediately throw a `CancellationError` and never reach the `if` statement.

Comment: “In Shortcuts app it stops as expected…, but on my Xcode console it still keeps counting…” - Can you clarify? Are you saying you are watching the Shortcuts execution on the Xcode console? Or are you saying that if you run it one way, it stops and if you run it another, it doesn't?

Comment: Bottom line, if you properly [`cancel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/cancel()), the [`Task.sleep`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(for:tolerance:clock:)) will definitely throw a [`CancellationError`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cancellationerror) and the loop will stop. So we need more details on this “on my Xcode console” scenario where it did not appear to stop.

Comment: @Rob My dev setup is I run the app in Xcode. Then open mac Shortcuts app separately, use the AppIntent that my running app provides, then watch progress in both Shortcuts app and Xcode console (I put some print statements in my app intent perform() ). I when I stop this action midway in Shortcuts, the progress in Shortcuts app stops, but in Xcode it still prints up to 10.